test_plates cs50 going wrong
I have the code for plates.py with conditions:

All vanity plates must start with at least two letters.”
vanity plates may contain a maximum of 6 characters (letters or numbers) and a minimum of 2 characters.”
“Numbers cannot be used in the middle of a plate; they must come at the end. For example, AAA222 would be an acceptable … vanity plate; AAA22A would not be acceptable. The first number used cannot be a ‘0’.”
“No periods, spaces, or punctuation marks are allowed.”


def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")

def is_valid(s):
    if 2 <= len(s) <= 6 and s.isalnum():
        if s.isalpha():
    # Check if the first two characters are letters
            return True
    # Check if there are no numbers in the middle
        firstnum = None
        for c in s:
            if c.isdigit():
                firstnum = c
                break
        if firstnum == None:
            return True
        if int(firstnum) == 0:
            return False
        ind = s.index(firstnum)
        pos = len(s) - ind
        for c in s[-pos:]:
            if not c.isdigit():
                return False
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


but for the input of 50, it shows valid. It should be invalid

I think I have come across this Harvard project and issue before.  Trying out your code, the item that stands out is your "isdigit" test.  All that is seems to do is check to see if a value in the license plate string is not a digit starting at the point in the string where the first digit is encountered.  So whether that is in the first position or other position, the test basically does not work.
With that in mind, following is a bit of refactored code that gets you closer to a type of validity testing for vanity plates regarding the first occurrence of digits.
def is_valid(s):
    if 2 <= len(s) <= 6 and s.isalnum():
        if s.isalpha():
    # Check if the first two characters are letters
            return True
    # Check if there are no numbers in the middle
        firstnum = None
        for c in s:
            if c.isdigit():
                firstnum = c
                break
        if firstnum == None:
            return True
        if int(firstnum) == 0:
            return False
        ind = s.index(firstnum)
        print("First number:", firstnum, "ind:", ind)
        pos = len(s) - ind
        for c in s[-pos:]:
            print("c:", c)
            if c.isdigit() and ind < 2: # Believe you need to also check where the digits start
                return False
        return True

I added some print statements to provide a bit of simplified debugging, but at the crux of the refactoring, checking where the first occurrence of a digit is also taken into account in determining the validity of a license plate.
With that, following are some quick tests at the terminal.
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/License$ python3 vanity.py 
Plate: 50
First number: 5 ind: 0
c: 5
Invalid
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/License$ python3 vanity.py 
Plate: CD50
First number: 5 ind: 2
c: 5
c: 0
Valid
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/License$ python3 vanity.py 
Plate: CD44FR
First number: 4 ind: 2
c: 4
c: 4
c: F
c: R
Valid

I did not exhaustively test out the possible scenarios, but this should highlight what was not working correctly and give you a path forward to possible further refinement.

yes, I have already used this debugging and tried various approaches. But, if I change anything in this code, the other scenarios such as "CS50"  and "ECT088" show invalid but these inputs should be valid as pass all the conditions specified in the problem.

I have used different "def" functions to represent different conditions, without changing any code lines. Then, it works.
